# Prove that this function is Riemann Integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $E:=\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Define $f$ on $[0,1]$ by 
>   $f(x)=\begin{cases}1 ~~~~~~~~\text{if $x\in E$}\\ 0~~~~~~~~\text{if $x\notin E$ }\end{cases}$.
>
> Show that f is Riemann integrable.

Here is my attempt.

Let $\epsilon >0$, define a partition $P_\epsilon$ of $[0,1]$ where $$P_\epsilon=\{0<x_1<x_2<...<1\}$$
On each subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ define the following sets:
$$A= \{i:[x_{i-1},x_i]\cap E=\emptyset\}$$
$$B= \{i:[x_{i-1},x_i]\cap E\neq \emptyset\}$$
Then $A\cap B=\emptyset $, for $i\in A$, $m_i=M_i=0$ and for $i\in B$, $m_i=0$, $M_i=1$

Thus, 
\begin{split}
U(f,P_\epsilon)-L(f,P_\epsilon)&= \sum_{i\in A} (M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i+\sum_{i\in B} (M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i\\
     &=\sum_{i\in B} 1 \times \Delta x_i\\
     \end{split}
Here is where I have a hard time in estimating the mesh of $P_\epsilon$ to get $U(f,P_\epsilon)-L(f,P_\epsilon)<\epsilon$.

I have seen different approaches to solving this problem but I think this approach seems more understanding.
Can someone please review my approach, modify or give me hints.

Comment: To evaluate the integral, there is a partition $P_{\epsilon,N}$ where $[0,\frac{1}{N+1}]$ is one of the subintervals and  each point $1, \frac{1}{2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{N}$ belongs to a subinterval of length $\epsilon 2^{-(n+1)}$. We then have  $$0 \leqslant \int_0^1f \leqslant U(P_{\epsilon,N},f) = \frac{\epsilon}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 2^{-n} + \frac{1}{N+1}\leqslant  \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \frac{1}{N+1}$$ Now take $N$ so large that the RHS is less than $\epsilon$. Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$ we must have $\int_0^1 f = 0$.

Comment: Very well  understood @RRL. But could this approach above be modified?

Comment: Well I marked this as duplicate because it has been asked so many times here. But I understand you want some comments on your approach.  To make your approach work you just need to add more detail about the partition.  It needs to be constructed so that intervals in the set $A$ where $\sup f = 1$ can be of arbitrarily small total length.  I just showed you how to do that.

Comment: I specified the lengths of intervals in $A$.  The other intervals can be anything because there is no contribution to the upper sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RRL

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider the partition $P$, such that:

$1).\ \epsilon$  is a partition point, so that if $n>1/ϵ, 1/n\in [0,\epsilon].$ Let $N\ge 2$ be the smallest integer for which this happens

and

$2).\ $  there are $x_k\in P$, such that $x_k<1/k<x_{k+1}$ and $x_{k+1}−x_k<\epsilon/2k$ for $k<N$.